# what is the right way to make a call recorder app which records both caller and the receiver's voice

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, call-recording

I am trying to build an call recording android app (Xamarin Android) .But I can't record both side of the call if I use 
   AudioSource to "Mic" 
It only records the Caller voice and not the receiver's voice.
and if I set Audio source to "VoiceCall" or "VoiceCommunication" it crashes.

This is my code:

```
      "AudioSavePathInDevice = 
        Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath+ "/" +"AudioRecording.3gp";
 mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mediaRecorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.VoiceCommunication);
            mediaRecorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.ThreeGpp);
            mediaRecorder.SetAudioEncoder((AudioEncoder.AmrNb));
           mediaRecorder.SetOutputFile(AudioSavePathInDevice);"
```

And these are the permission i am asking for:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

I am Debugging in android 8.1 Oreo device(Redmi note 5 pro).

kindly help me with this problem

Comment: Please, be more specific. You should provide relevant snippets of code, layouts, etc. Have a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, have a detailed look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is there an error message? Or there is no request for runtime permissions ?

Comment: whenever i choose any audioSource except Mic  "Unhandled Exception:

Java.Lang.RuntimeException: start failed. occurred " this exception is showing.I have asked for the above permissions in runtime.

Comment: try to add  `mediaRecorder.SetAudioSamplingRate(11205);` ,if still not work,maybe the device manufacturers don't support this as some device manufacturers don't support